# How does contextual add in works in outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in for Outlook - that fetches the attachment from the email.

Next, I am looking for how to use contextual API to highlight some words on the email based on the regex.

For testing purposes, I am using an example: `Selected entities and Regex matches (Item Read, contextual) (2)` from https://script-lab.azureedge.net/

**EDIT:**

I was able to see the pop-up on the highlighted text in the mail.

So, the concern here is I am unable to run my javascript file i.e., `contextual.js`.

**Note:** I am able to see the `contextual.html` in the pop-up - meaning the UI coming from HTML.

**How to link `contextual.js` with the rest of the project ?**

I tried the one with MS provides https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-In-Contextual-Regex didn’t work either.

Would be really appreciable if I could get a sample running which have both contextual and taskpane?

So, here is the below folder structure I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the entity is found it will be highlighted in the message body, so when a user clicks on it - a pop-up can be displayed to a user. Read more about that in the [Contextual Outlook add-ins](https://github.com/keyur32/add-in-docs-new/blob/master/docs/outlook/contextual-outlook-add-ins.md) article.